# Connection reset when connecting to docker container

Tags: apache, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

```
# Import ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update

# setup sftp
#   Setup the directory
EXPOSE 21
RUN mkdir -p /var/ftp/pub
RUN chmod 777 /var/ftp/pub
#   install the software
RUN apt-get install vsftpd -y
#   move the config
COPY vsftpd.conf /etc
#   Run FTP
# RUN service vsftpd restart



# setup webpage
RUN apt-get install apache2 -y
COPY index.html /var/www/html
RUN echo "ServerName 0.0.0.0" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN service apache2 restart
EXPOSE 80
```

With this dockerfile, I'm trying to setup an ubuntu instance with FTP and Apache. The apache port is 80 and yet when I navigate to localhost:80 on my host machine I only get connection reset. Is this config correct?

Comment: You need to run one service in a container, and it needs to be a foreground process.  `RUN service ... start` doesn’t actually do anything.

Comment: add ```RUN apachectl -D FOREGROUND```? Edit: I see what you're saying now. Is it possible to run more than one or do I need to run one and do some networking between them

Answer (score 0):

Using `RUN` directive, you can run any command to an image during build time. while the apache is supposed to start at container starting time, So you need to add the process starting command in `CMD` or `entrypoint`.

So replace `RUN service apache2 restart` with `CMD` below.

```
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```